# Flutter plugin native iOS func handle not being called

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, flutter, dart

So, I am developing my first flutter plugin in iOS but I am unable to make native method to work.

For example, from the boiler plate code, I have

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MobileFlutter {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('xyz_client');

// Asking this channel to invoke method get platform version
  static Future<String?> get platformVersion async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version+"d";
  }
}
```

and then in iOS

`SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin.swift` I have this

```
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "xyz_client", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }
  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    if ("getPlatformVersion" == call.method) {
        result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
    } 
}
```

I  used debugger but it never comes to this point.

```
public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult)
```

Ps: `public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {` is being called.

Can someone help me in debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consulting [this](https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/blob/master/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin.swift#L15) sample code, I suppose the difference is that the `handle` function is meant to be in the class `SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin`. Like:

```swift
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "xyz_client", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = SwiftMobileFlutterPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    if ("getPlatformVersion" == call.method) {
        result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
    } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
I moved it inside class but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you use debugger to check if `handle` is being called now?

Comment: I did. it's not being called.

Comment: At this point, I can recommend double-checking if you're calling the correct methods and such. Is your full code hosted publically?

Comment: Haha. Stupid me. 
I actually tried what you said but forgot to call that method from dart side. 
Thanks for looking into it bro :)